# Change saturation with javascipt

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I am wondering how using javascript I can create something where when a function occurs, the saturation of the body will be changed. I am currently using css to acomplish this but I need a way to switch instead to javascript.

Current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
  body {
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}</style>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="saturationAdjust()">
  Change saturation
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```

When the function  `saturationAdjust()` occurs, the saturation of the body should be changed from the default to (4). This is an example using css: `filter: saturate(4);`. This filter should be applied when the function occurs. How can this be done?

Comment: Not related to the filter, but if  you want the mountains not to be squished up on smaller (narrower aspect) devices background-size: contain can help.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll look into for later. It's just a very basic demo i put together, not my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class in your stylesheet and then add that class to the body. Conversely if yo ever want to remove the class you can do that using the remove function on the element's classList.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
  body {
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.saturate {
  filter: saturate(4);
}
</style>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="saturationAdjust()"></button>
  <script>
  function saturationAdjust() {
    document.body.classList.add('saturate');
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested the code and it isn't working. I'm not sure exactly why, the button tag wasn't closed but I closed the tag and the code still isn't working.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by not working? Is the new class added to the body element (check in your browser's inspector). When I run it it does add the class, but there is no noticable effect on the element.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the mistake, the code is running fine, I forgot that the effect won't have an effect on the background image. Sorry again. Thank you for the code!

Comment: If you put the background on a div within the body it has an effect - sorry I should have spotted the difference.